# Programmatically setting selector xml resourse as drawable to ImageView is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-resources

I need to populate `ListView` with icon and their title. I have created array in resources for menu icon and their title like:

For titles:

```
   <array name="menu_title_array">
         <item>@string/menu_name_text</item>
    </array>
```

For icons:

```
<array name="menu_icons_array">
     <item>@drawable/menu_icon_name</item>
</array>
```

I have created a drawable for each icon using xml selector drawable like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_name_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_name_press" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_name_press" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_name"/>
</selector>
```

Now I am creating a list of MenuItems that contains `title` and `drawable` from array that I have created `menu_title_array` and `menu_icons_array`like:

```
       TypedArray titles = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.menu_title_array);
        TypedArray icons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.menu_icons_array);
for (int index = 0; index < menuRowText.length(); mainMenuIndex++) {
    menuRowItemList.add(new MenuRowItem(icons.getDrawable(index), titles.getString(index ));
}
```

Now I am setting title and their icon in adapter `getView()` method like this:

```
title.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
icon.setImageDrawable(menuItem.getDrawable());
```

Now if I select a menu item then state of the icon should change according to the `<selector>` I had created for it. ***But it's not changing it's state.***

If I create a `StateListDrawable` for each menu item like:

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
       mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_name_press));
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_activated},
       mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_name_press));
states.addState(new int[] { },
       mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_name));
```

and apply it to list icon like:

```
icon.setImageDrawable(states);
```

***then it is working correctly as it's changing it's state activated, pressed.***

Please suggest where I am going wrong, I not want to create icon drawable using `StateListDrawable` for each MenuItem, as there will be lot of boiler plate code in app.

ListView is populating using `List<MenuRowItem>`. Here is the structure of following pojo:

```
class MenuRowItem {
    private Drawable drawable;
    private String title;

MenuRowItem(Drawable drawable, String title) {
    this.drawable = drawable;
    this.title = title;
}

public Drawable getDrawable() {
        return drawable;
}

public String getText() {
        return mText;
}
```

Let me know if more details needed.

Comment: in `icon.setImageDrawable(menuItem.getDrawable());` what is `menuItem` ? it is not declared **anywhere**

Comment: @pskink ListView adapter is populating with List<MenuRowItem>.

Comment: I have updated MenuRowItem in question details. Please have a look and let me know if more details needed. I am not updating full code because there lot of other code. Thanks

Comment: and what is `mainMenuIndex` ? nobody will answer help you with such unclear questions

Comment: I am iterating the TypedArray that is defained in xml resources and creating MenuRowItem from it. I have update the code with for loop. Please have a look. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Why have you incremented value of `mainMenuIndex` instead of `index` in for loop?

Comment: @Apurva: you are right I am using mainMenuIndex in code not index. Here I put the code snippet only not all implemented code, as I doing other work as well for creating the MenuRowItem list.

Comment: I just checked and found it's not working properly because pressed, activated, normal state of a drawable is lossing when I am setting it as member variable in MenuRowItem. So is this the reason why state of selected menu item is not changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved issue by keeping the `id` of `drawable` in `MenuRowItem` instead of keeping `Drawable` object.

Here is POJO for `MenuRowItem` now:

```
class MenuRowItem {
private int drawableResourceId;
private String title;

MenuRowItem(int resourceId, String title) {
    this.drawableResourceId = resourceId;
    this.title = title;
}

public int getResourceId() {
        return drawableResourceId;
}

public String getText() {
        return mText;
}
}
```

I beleive state of `Drawable(enable, activated, normal)` loss while keeping the drawable as object.
Hence I kept resourceId of drawable in POJO and set drawable to ImageView in adapter using:

```
icon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(item.getResourceId()));
```

Hope it would help someone. Let me know if more info needed

Comment: "Hope it would help someone." You definitely helped me today. I had the exact same issue, and this solution resolved it. Your theory makes sense to me.